Usage of the admin-api in shopware 6 plugins
Is there a "right" way to consume the Shopware Admin API inside a plugin?
I'm looking for the equivalent of the JS function loginService.getToken(), which provides the necessary authentication tokens in the administration frontend. Although I believe there is no direct counterpart, since in a plugin context we don't have a user, the plugin is still running inside the Shopware core, so it should be possible to authenticate it.
To be specific: We need to call the POST Ship order completely (German documentation) function from Pickware. For now, we are just calling the class directly, e.g.:
$shippedQuantity = $this->orderShippingService->shipOrderCompletely($orderId, $warehouseId, $context);
(I can't share the Pickware controller due to copyright, but I don't think it is needed here to understand the question.)
My problem here is that we are relying on an internal class from Pickware, which can change at any time. The routing, however, is (or feels) more consistent.
So, should plugins consume the Admin API directly, or is this a misuse of the Shopware ecosystem?
